# Issue with cts:field-word-query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have created a field named 'publication-titles' in my MarkLogic database (say ABC) based on element XPath.

The following query works fine on QC with Content Source as database 'ABC' (in which field exists)

```
let $text := 'The Point'

let $query := cts:field-word-query("publication-titles", $text, 
("punctuation-sensitive", "case-insensitive", "whitespace-sensitive"), 5.0)

return
  xdmp:invoke-function(function()
    {
      cts:search(/Publication, $query)[1]
    },
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <database>{xdmp:database("ABC")}</database>
    </options>
  )
```

However, if I change the Content Source to any other database, I get the following error

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-NOFIELD: cts:search(fn:collection()/Publication, cts:field-    
word-query("publication-titles", "The Point", ("case- 
insensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive","lang=en"), 5)) - 
- Field not defined: publication-titles
Stack Trace
At line 8 column 8:
In function() as item()*()

6. xdmp:invoke-function(function()
7. {
8. cts:search(/Publication, $query)[1]
9. },
10. <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(replaced answer)

It looks like you have hit an unfortunate bug that seems to apply to all `cts:field-*-query` query constructors, but not to any of the others (not thoroughly verified).

Inline functions have the difficulty that they carry along context from where they are invoked as well as their own, so that explains potential references to the wrong database. It can be tricky to apply to correct context. I have filed a bug report, so hopefully this gets resolved soon in one of the next patch releases.

In the meantime, it is best to enforce the query constructor to get re-evaluated in the inner context. You can do that by serializing the query to XML, and parsing it inside the inline function. That is fairly easy to do. Wrap the constructor with `document { .. }/*`, and to parse it you use `cts:query($query)`:

```
let $text := 'The Point'

let $query := document{
  cts:field-word-query("publication-titles", $text, 
("punctuation-sensitive", "case-insensitive", "whitespace-sensitive"), 5.0)
}/*

return
  xdmp:invoke-function(function()
    {
      cts:search(/Publication, cts:query($query))[1]
    },
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <database>{xdmp:database("ABC")}</database>
    </options>
  )
```

There is a very small penalty for the serialize and parsing, but that is likely negligible compared to the actual search time.

HTH!

Comment: grtjn, I know that. Notice that I am explicitly executing this query against 'ABC' database using xdmp:invoke-function(). I am just changing the database throught Content Source option in Query Console. Also, it doesn't matter whether I build the cts:field-word-query inside or outside of the xdmp:invoke-function(), I still get the same error. By the way, I am on ML version 8.0-3.

Comment: Ah, overlooked the xdmp:invoke-function, getting the same locally. Let me ask around internally..

Comment: A colleague confirmed that it seems to happen with cts:field-*-query, but not with for instance cts:element-range-query. Sounds like you discovered a bug..

Comment: I confirm that this is not an issue with cts: field-value-query.

Comment: now that I can't use cts:field-word-query(), I wonder how I can use cts:element-word-query() to consider special characters ($,#,@,&,e tc.) as words. I used tokenizer overrides with my field to include these characters as words. Can you think of any other way of searching special characters inside XML elements?

Answer (score 2):

Certain query constructors have dependencies on the execution context. Field queries and range or geospatial queries have the most obvious dependency (does the index exist? what are its parameters?), but value and word queries also look at the configuration to determine whether they are position sensitive or enabled at all. When you put the constructor outside the invoke-function, it will be called in the outer configuration. Often this won't make a material difference, but in many cases it will, or it will make a subtle difference (e.g. failing to use positions when you should have). There is no way to make this work in the way you'd like, any more than we could make a call to `xdmp:database()` work in that context.

Things should work if you just perform the same call inside the function body (i.e. just put the same let/return in there). The bug is that this too doesn't work, because the constructors incorrectly think they can be optimized in a way that the outer context executes them in the optimization phase. I'll fix this under 50017.